# Tengo un error al programar en Python él error es un Atribute Error

Tags: python, nltk

Estoy haciendo un código en Python que tiene el siguiente error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-8361347cc7ca> in <cell line: 21>()
         19 lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer
         20 
    ---> 21 Untitleyd4 = json.load(open('Untitled4.json').read())
         22 
         23 words = []
    
    /usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
        291     kwarg; otherwise ``JSONDecoder`` is used.
        292     """
    --> 293     return loads(fp.read(),
        294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
        295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
    
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Este sería el código principal al completo del cual proviene el error por si quieres verlo detalladamente :

```
import nltk; nltk.download('popular')
    nltk.download('punkt')
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    nltk.download('omw-1.4')
    
    !pip install matplotlib-venn
    import random
    import json
    import pickle
    import numpy as np
    
    import nltk
    from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
    
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer
    
    Untitleyd4 = json.load(open('Untitled4.json').read())
    
    words = []
    classes = []
    documents = []
    ignore_letters = ['?','!','¿','.',',']
    
    for intent in intents ['intents']:
       for pattern in intent['paterns']:
         word_list=nltk.world.tokenize(patern)
         words.extend(word_list)
         documents.append((word_list,intent["tag"]))
         if intent ["tag"] not in classes:
          classes.append(intend["tag"])
    
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
    words = sorted(set(words))
    
    pickle.dump(words,open('words.pkl','wb' ))
    pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))
    
    training = []
    output_empty = [0]*len(classes)
    for document in documents:
      bag = []
      word_patterns = document[0]
      word_patterns=[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower())for word in word_patterns]
      for word in words:
        bag.append(1)if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)
        output_row[classes.indx(documen[1])] = 1
        training.append([bag,output_row])
    random.shuffle(training)
    training = np.array(training)
    print(training)
    
    train_x = list(training)[:,0]
    train_y = list(train[:,1])
    
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0])))
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, sería genial que coloques que hace el código también. Tanto como comentar el código y explicado que es lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer una ia

Answer (score 0):

`json.load` espera un *file pointer* como primer argumento, un objeto que implemente el método `read()`, generalmente un archivo de texto o binario que contenga un JSON.

En tu caso, en la linea:

```
Untitleyd4 = json.load(open('Untitled4.json').read())
```

le estas pasando `open('Untitled4.json').read()`, la salida de leer un archivo de texto, que es una cadena. `str` no tiene un método `read` obviamente, de ahí el error. Debes pasar el archivo, no su contenido:

```
Untitleyd4 = json.load(open('Untitled4.json'))
```

Mejor aun:

```
with open('Untitled4.json') as json_file:
    Untitleyd4 = json.load(json_file)
```

También existe `json.loads` (terminado en "s" de "string") que si acepta una cadena representando un JSON como entrada (también un objeto `bytes` o `bytearray`), por lo que si podrías hacer:

```
Untitleyd4 = json.loads(open('Untitled4.json').read())
```

pero no tiene mucho sentido en este caso.

Comment: Michas gracias.

Comment: Ahora me pone: intents isn't defined por la linea 29

Comment: Porque efectivamente `intents` no existe en el código  antes de intentar iterar en el for con  `for intent in intents ['intents']:`. Sin saber que se  supone que hace el código y sin poder reproducirlo es complicado, ¿que debe ser `intents`? ¿es el JSON como creo? Si es así, cambia `Untitleyd4 = json.load(json_file)` por  `intents = json.load(json_file)`.

Comment: Si es el JSON estoy haciendo una ia, muchas gracias

Comment: Me sale un keyerror: intents a pesar de sustituir lo que estaba mal por esto: intents = json.load(json_file)

Comment: Si el error te lo da en `intents ['intents']`, `intent['paterns']` o `intent['tag"]` es porque alguna de las claves no están en el JSON o en la parte del mismo en la que la buscas (dependiendo de donde te de el error, o "intents" no esta como clave en el objeto padre o  "paterns"/"tag" no están en todos  los objetos intern. Habría que ver la estructura del JSON.

Comment: Este sería él JSON, en los tags,etc hay preguntas, respuestas,etc pero las quite por motivos personales :{"intents":[
    {

             "tag":"saludo",
        "patterns": [""],
        "responses":[""]

    },
    {
              "tag":"nombre",
        "patterns": [""],
        "responses":[""]


    },

]

 }

Comment: Hola Pablo, tienes un error tipográfico en     `for pattern in intent['paterns']:`, debe ser     `for pattern in intent['patterns']:` (falta una "t" en "patterns"). Aparte de eso, con ese JSON no deberías tener ningún error en esa parte del código; https://python-fiddle.com/saved/qOw7G7029FxYRkS5pjcE

Comment: Me da keyerror 'intents'

Comment: Lo que te esta diciendo el error es que el objeto resultante de parsear el JSON  (un diccionario) no tiene la calve "intents", lo cual no puede pasar con el codigo y el JSON que afirmas tener como puedes comprobar en el ejemplo online que te agrego arriba. ¿Que te imprime la siguiente linea `import json; print(json.load(open('Untitled4.json')).keys())` si la agregas al inicio de tu script o la ejecutas en el interprete interactivo?

Comment: Me sigue saltando esto:NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8ccc0140bd62> in <cell line: 28>()
     26 ignore_letters = ['?','!','¿','.',',']
     27 
---> 28 for intent in intents['intents']:
     29    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
     30      word_list=nltk.world.tokenize(pattern)

NameError: name 'intents' is not defined